# Почему "роз-", а не "раз-"?

Tags: орфография

В предыдущем ответе указали, что правильно писать "оперативно-разыскная деятельность", т.к. в безударном слоге пишется "раз-", а не "роз-". Но тогда почему официальное название закона "Об оперативно-рОзызыскной деятельности" и в тексте постановлений Конституционного суда также написано рОзыскная? Может есть какие-то исключения из общего правила?

Answer (score 1):

*С сайта грамота.ру
Слово розыскной закрепилось в русском языке в таком написании в 30-е годы XX века. Несмотря на то что написание через А предлагалось и в Толковом словаре под редакцией Д. Н. Ушакова (1939), и в первоначальном проекте академического «Орфографического словаря русского языка» под ред. С. И. Ожегова (1952, корректура), оно так и не вошло тогда в орфографические словари.*

*Сейчас написание разыскной вместо розыскной рекомендовано в качестве нормативного для устранения неоговоренного в своде 1956 г. исключения из правила написания приставки роз-/раз-. Написание этой приставки не подчиняется общему правилу употребления букв на месте безударных гласных: здесь в безударной позиции пишется буква А, хотя под ударением только О, напр.: раздать, но розданный; расписать, но роспись, разливать, но розлив. Поэтому и для слова разыскной не действует проверка словом розыск. Следует писать: разыскивать, разыскной, разыскник, оперативно-разыскной, следственно-разыскной, служебно-разыскной и т. п.*
Написание «разыскной»  было предложено в первом издании «Русского орфографического словаря» РАН 1999 года (и во всех последующих изданиях); в «Большом толковом словаре русского языка» под ред. С. А. Кузнецова (СПб., 2003), «Грамматическом словаре русского языка» А. А. Зализняка (5-е изд., М., 2008), полном академическом справочнике «Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации» (М., 2006) и многих других изданиях.
Однако в законотворчестве эта норма так и не соблюдалась.Закон действительно называется  «Об оперативно-рОзыскной деятельности»
Деятельность начали переименовывать из «оперативно-розыскной» в «оперативно-разыскную» по инициативе министра МВД Рашида Нургалиева пять лет назад, например переименовали кафедру ОРД в академии МВД».

Answer (score 0):

Исключений из ЭТОГО правила нет. Деятельность *оперативно-рАзыскная.* Во всех словарях в слове рАзыскной в приставке пишется А. По поводу официального названия закона - no comments! Видимо "писатели" нашли проверочной слово - рОзыск :-))

Comment: О том и говорится, что исключение, существовавшее с 30-х годов, устраняется.